# Display Map in winui3 with Mapsui and a separated ViewModel file

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, winui-3, mapsui

I am trying to display a map in Winui3 with Mapsui and a separate MVVM file. Just to getting started.

If I'm using MapControl in ViewModel file i get multiple null errors and with Map it just doesnt show up.

I just trying to [follow the getting started](https://mapsui.com/documentation/getting-started-winui.html) but with a ViewModel file.
With MapControl

**ViewModel with MapControl(a lot of nulls errors):**

```
public class MyMapViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private Map _map;
        public Map Map
        {
            get { return _map; }
            set
            {
                _map = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Map)));
            }
        }

        public MyMapViewModel()
        {
            Map = new Map();
            Map.Layers.Add(OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer());
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel with Map**

```
 public class MyMapViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private Map _map;
        public Map Map
        {
            get { return _map; }
            set
            {
                _map = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Map)));
            }
        }

        public MyMapViewModel()
        {
            Map = new Map();
            Map.Layers.Add(OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer());
        }
    }
```

**Code-behind file**

```
    public sealed partial class MapsuiMVVMControl : UserControl
    {
        public MapsuiMVVMControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MapViewModel();
        }
    }
```

**Xaml for code-behind file**

```
<Grid>
        <!--<Grid.DataContext>
            <vm:MyMapViewModel />
        </Grid.DataContext>-->
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <vm:MapViewModel />
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <winui:MapControl x:Name="MyMap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, using viewModels is good, but I think you did not understand the purpose of a viewmodel. The mapsui maps component is actually a control where the user can interact with. And because of being a control, it must be manipulated in the code behind file of the page => the model. So what you can do (and sure this works) :

C#
'''

```
public sealed partial class YourPage : Page
{
   public YourPage()
   {
      this.InitializeComponent();
      MyMap.Map.Layers.Add(OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer());
   }
}
```

'''

Xaml:
'''
`<mapsui:MapControl x:Name="MyMap" />`
'''

Link to this:
https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2023/07/25/displaying-maps-in-winui-3-with-open-source-libraries/
Hope this helps, otherwise let me know